# Cannot read property 'pageX' of null

Tags: reactjs, d3.js

using d3(v5) and reactjs and **d3-context-menu** for showing context menu after right clicking on an svg file.

I'm receiving the following error:
thanks for your answer

> TypeError: Cannot read property 'pageX' of null

and this is my code:
[Updated]

```
  import * as d3 from "d3";
  import contextMenuFactory from "d3-context-menu";

    componentDidMount() {
    svg.onload = () => {
          let svgDoc = svg.contentDocument;
          let svgContextMenu = d3.select(svgDoc);
     let contextMenu = contextMenuFactory(d3);
          var menu = [
            {
              title: "Item #1",
              action: function(d, i) {
                console.log("Item #1 clicked!");
                console.log("The data for this circle is: " + d);
              },
              disabled: false // optional, defaults to false
            },
            {
              title: "Item #2",
              action: function(d, i) {
                console.log("You have clicked the second item!");
                console.log("The data for this circle is: " + d);
              }
            }
          ];
          svgContextMenu.selectAll("g").on("contextmenu", contextMenu(menu));

    }
```

Comment: How you declared `svgContextMenu`?

Comment: @Emanuele Scarabattoli yes...

Comment: Sorry, I lost a part of the script...